# Want to write a batch job which will check computer is in locked state(screensaver is coming) or not and perform necessary actions?

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
set strComputer = "." ;indicates the local machine
set strKeyPath = "Control Panel\Desktop"
set ValueName = "ScrnSave.exe"
set strValue = RegQueryValue( @REGCURRENT, StrCat(strKeyPath, '[', ValueName,']')) 
set strValue = StrReplace(strValue, "\", "\\")
set objWMIService = GetObject(StrCat("winmgmts:\\" , strComputer , "\root\cimv2"))
set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(StrCat("Select * From Win32_Process Where ExecutablePath ='" , strValue , "'"))
If "colItems.Count" >0 Then
    Message("Notice", "The computer is locked.")
   cd C:\Program Files\Common Files\Pulse Secure\Integration
   pulselauncher.exe -signout <URL>
Else
    Message("Notice", "The computer is not locked.")
End If
```

Is this code correct?? If so i am getting > was not expected in this time. Also is there any efficient script way or script to check the computer is locked or not??

Comment: What language is that? It's not batch/cmd

Comment: No your code is not correct. Please begin by opening a Command Prompt window, then enter `set /?`, before reading the output. After you've learned that command and corrected your code, please open another Command Prompt window, then enter `if /?`, before reading the output. After you've learned how to use the command, correct your code as necessary. Next you need to learn how to quote file paths which include spaces or problematic characters. Finally please take a look at some VBScript tutorials, as your code seems more like it is intended for that language

Comment: For those that are intrerested, the OP has not created the code at all, it is a direct copy from [here](https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WinBatch/How~To+Check~if~Computer~is~Locked~or~Idle.txt), with two lines inserted as a guess.

Comment: Hi compo,

Thanks for the reply. I want to put this script in scheduler so it will run in background and  do the necessary stuff. And yes winbatch site is showing that was script. Do you have any other alternatives to do?

Comment: @aritchakraborty - WinBatch is a third party language and is completely unrelated to batch; it's like comparing Java and Javascript. Thankfully, this question has an answer on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1170918/determine-remote-windows-screen-locked-or-unlocked-remotely